# Regression romance manhwa where a timid unloved girl marries the unloved crown prince in her first life

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m looking for a manhwa about a timid girl who wasn’t loved by her family, and married the crown prince who wasn’t treated well either.

The crown prince thinks of himself as a monster because he has special powers from his mother, but they both fall in love with each other. The special powers takes lifespan away and since she married him, it took from her instead (she knew because king told her; the crown prince didn’t know).

She dies years after marriage, due to a war where he used his powers a lot. She regresses and is more confident as she tries to maneuver the social climate where the second prince wants her (she just wants her husband back).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead or the prince?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is ***[Please Marry Me Again!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/2bp77ee/please-marry-me-again-husband)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> As a so-called "half-noblewoman", Shurya Littenheim was shunned by all in high society except her husband, Grand Duke Kardi Esperand. So when the powers Kardi inherited from his family start to slowly kill him, Shurya gladly makes a deal to sacrifice her own life instead. Upon her death, she's reborn as her younger, single self, and this time... she's doing it all over again! Shurya's on a mission to make Kardi her hubby once more, but is there any hope of avoiding yet another tragic ending?

The main character, Siera Littenheim, is the illegitimate daughter of a duke and most of her family despises her, so she arranges a political marriage with a prince, Kardi Esperand, to get away from them.

Kardi thinks of himself as a monster as he has a power passed down through his bloodline which makes him a formidable weapon for his father on the battlefield, but drains his lifespan, such that he isn't expected to live past 30. Siera falls in love with him, and makes a secret deal with his father to share the burden of Kardi's power, so that her lifespan would be shortened instead of his.

Kardi subsequently learns of this arrangement when she dies ten years after their wedding and is heartbroken, wishing he could see her just one more time. She then wakes up back in her father's mansion, shortly before her wedding with Kardi.